# What is the efficient way to read 1TB HDFS csv file using python

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have a file which is placed in HDFS. I would like to know what is efficient way to read file using python. can i use pyspark.?

Comment: 1 Tb csv file? Gooby pls

Comment: Did you **try** Spark?

Comment: The "efficient" way would be to 1) Not use CSV in Hadoop - convert it to Parquet 2) define a Hive table over it and use Presto or Impala, if you have those available. Otherwise, Hive or Spark

Comment: Check out Dask.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the data?  HDFS and YARN are pretty efficient at processing the data but the actual tool you need is defined by the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PySpark` which is a `Python API for Spark`. It will allow you to leverage cluster resources using `Spark`. I would recommend taking a smaller sized chunk of the 1 TB file, and testing your code on that. If all looks good, then you can submit your job on the larger dataset.

If using Spark: Depending upon how much memory you have on the cluster, consider caching the `RDDs` in memory that you plan to reuse frequently. This will speed up your job executions.